# ArcRotationCamera - left/right scroll moving in the scene without rotation

Tags: babylonjs

I'm using the arcRotationCamera. When I select the left or right arrow in the keyboard, the scene rotates to left or right.
I want to disable this rotation and add a left or right scroll moving like the overflow-x: scroll

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set:

```
camera.keysLeft =  [];
camera.keysRight = []
```

Then you can register an event handler for `keydown` event and do what you want with it